# Order By With Multiple Foreign Keys to the Same Table

Tags: t-sql

Sorry if this is a n00b question. I'm no T-SQL expert, but I have a working understanding. I'm going to try to make this clear, but it's sort of confusing to begin with.

## The Problem

I have two tables. Table A represents an item, and Table B represents relationships between the items.

Table A: ItemID, Name,...

Table B: ParentID, ThisID, ChildID

The problem I'm facing is that all three IDs in Table B, point to primary keys in Table A, but I need to order the results by A.Name in groups for each relationship role (if that makes sense).

So, if Table A has:

```
1 ItemZ
2 ItemA
3 ItemD
4 ItemX
5 ItemT
```

and Table B has:

```
1 3 5
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2 3
2 4 5
1 2 5
```

I would want the results returned to be grouped by the parent item's name, then the "this" item name, then the child item's name... in this scenario:

```
2(A) 4(X) 5(T)
1(Z) 2(A) 3(D)
1(Z) 2(A) 5(T)
1(Z) 2(A) 4(X)
1(Z) 3(D) 5(T)
1(Z) 3(D) 4(X)
```

## The Question

How can I use `ORDER BY` on the same field (Table A.Name) while maintaining the grouping?

## Note

I've read this: [SQL Ordering by Date but Maintain Foreign Key Groupings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165999/sql-ordering-by-date-but-maintain-foreign-key-groupings) but I don't think the answer fits my question. I looked for my question on here and on Google, but I can't find a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables together so you can link the ID in Table `B` with the name in Table `A`.  Since you have three different ID's in Table `B` that link to Table `A`, you will need to join in Table `A` three times.  To keep things organized, I recommend using aliases like `A_Parent`, `A_Child`, `A_This`.  Here is an example that should order as expected:

```
select
  B.ParentID, B.ThisID, B.ChildID
from
  TableB B
join
  TableA A_Parent on A_Parent.ItemID = B.ParentID
join
  TableA A_This on A_This.ItemID = B.ThisID
join
  TableA A_Child on A_Child.ItemID = B.ChildID
order by
  A_Parent.Name, A_This.Name, A_Child.Name
```

Sample Output ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a45e0/1)):

```
PARENTID | THISID | CHILDID
-----------------------
  2      |  4     |  5
  1      |  2     |  3
  1      |  2     |  5
  1      |  2     |  4
  1      |  3     |  5
  1      |  3     |  4
```

Comment: `ORDER BY A_Parent.Name, A_This.Name, A_Child.Name` was what I needed. Thanks!